# Notification sound goes infinity and never stop

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I made a notification with sound and when it notify make sound but never stop. Is there any way to limit the notification's sound time?

this is my notification code

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setContentTitle(title).setContentText(detail);

mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS);


SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager
    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

String sound = pref.getString("ringtonePref", "default");
Uri uri = Uri.parse(sound);
mBuilder.setSound(uri,RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
```

Comment: notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
 notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem. I used NotificationBuilder to build everything. Called build() to get the noti object and I did the following:

```
notification.sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
notification.audioStreamType = AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION;
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to change `TYPE_ALARM` to `TYPE_NOTIFICATION`.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the ringtones contain `ANDROID_LOOP` metadata to make the music loop. 
These sounds will loop forever. So it is better to use sounds specific for default notifications or sounds that doesn't have `ANDROID_LOOP` metadata.